# Magento sets null value for non-selected attribute value in admin. It affects the frontend display. How to deal with it?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've created a new attribute (type: dropdown) that is not a required field.

At this moment, every product shows in the frontend "**my attribute: n/a**".

After save anything in some product, magento write a *null*  value inside catalog_product_entity_int table for this attribute.

But in the frontend the attribute now appear as "**my attribute: No**" instead of "N/A".

It looks like a bug, since I didn't touch in the attribute while editing the new product.

Is there a way to deal with it or to apply some rule in my phtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not a bug. It's a feature.
`N/A` is displayed when there is no record in the table `catalog_product_entity_int` for that attribute.
When you add an attribute there are no values for that attribute for any product, but as soon as you save a product that has that attribute, a null value is inserted in the table (as you stated). So `no value` is different from `null value`.
All the magic happens here `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes::getAdditionalData()`.
These are the lines that interest you:

```
if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) { // no value in the database
    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
} elseif ((string)$value == '') { // empty value in the database
    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');  
}
```

If you want to change anything override this method.
If you change anything you might want to take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List::getProductAttributeValue()`.
The same system is used for displaying attribute values in the compare products list.

Comment: Thank you Marius. I will create a module to override it. But I guess it should be treated as a bug since '' doesn't mean 'No', it means I have no value too, or that I've set '' for something. 
For example, if I create a "warranty" attribute and doesn't select a value for the existing products, it doens't mean that products doesnt have warranty, but that I dont have this info available at the moment. Dont you think?

Comment: @RicardoMartins. I think it matters how you look at the problem. If you look at it your way you are right, if you look at it from the Magento Team's way, they are right. I really have no opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up to create 2 observers... One that overrides *getValue* from **Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default** and other to override *getAdditionalData* in **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes** as follows:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default{
    public function getValue(Varien_Object $object)
    {
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());

        if (in_array($this->getConfigField('input'), array('select','boolean'))) {
            $valueOption = $this->getOption($value);
            if (!$valueOption) {
                $opt     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean');
                $options = $opt->getAllOptions();
                if ($options && !is_null($value)) { //added !is_null
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        if ($option['value'] == $value ) {
                            $valueOption = $option['label'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $value = $valueOption;
        } elseif ($this->getConfigField('input') == 'multiselect') {
            $value = $this->getOption($value);
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = implode(', ', $value);
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Product_View_Attributes extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes
{
    public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
    {
        $data = array();
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode()) || (string)$value == '') { //modified
                    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
                }

                if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                        'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }   
}
```